# Enforcing the non-existence of relationships in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

In Neo4j, is there a way of enforcing that a node of a label `X` is not connected to a node of label `Y`?

For example, if someone tried to run a query such as:

```
MERGE (:X)-[:SOME_RELATIONSHIP]->(:Y)
```

would there be a way to guarantee that such a query would fail?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neo4j's constraints don't currently support relationship existence or restriction, so you'd need to put in some extra work.

If you have APOC Procedures, you could [register a trigger](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_triggers) which could get evaluated to check if a relationship being created connects two nodes of those labels and use `apoc.util.validate()` to generate an error which will fail and rollback the transaction.

If you want to do this without APOC, it's a bit more work, as you'll need to create a TransactionEventHandler, and then a kernel extension to load your event handler. [Here's a blog entry on this approach](https://maxdemarzi.com/2015/03/25/triggers-in-neo4j/).